# Trouble Logging in - python requests (Possibly with cookies?)

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I would like to login to a website. I believe there is a captcha upon logging in, but I've heard it is possible to get past it by avoiding automation detection in the first place.

Here is my code:

```
def requests_bot():
    session = requests.session()
    login_url = 'url'
    proxies = {"http": "191.96.42.106:3129",
               "https": "191.96.42.106:3129"}

    headers = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
               'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
               'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8',
               'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
               'Connection': 'keep-alive',
               'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
               'Cookie': '__utmz=111701652.1565116553.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utma=111701652.2083351365.1565116553.1565186134.1565235768.6; __utmc=111701652; __utmt=1; PLAY_SESSION=dbb31e7a1f68d47e85378d510c2fd7a0ec50fa7b-___AT=bfc97239f07a85ccb09e0cbce1555a2ea2abe062&___ID=19621b5b-c02d-4c68-99ec-919ae3d4d408&showInfoBar=false; __utmb=111701652.8.8.1565235799038',
               'Host': 'account.mojang.com',
               'Origin': 'https://account.mojang.com',
               'Referer': 'https://account.mojang.com/login',
               'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
               'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36'}

    cookies = {"__utmz": "111701652.1565116553.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)",
               "__utma": "111701652.2083351365.1565116553.1565186134.1565235768.6",
               "__utmc": "111701652",
               "__utmt": "1",
               "PLAY_SESSION": "dbb31e7a1f68d47e85378d510c2fd7a0ec50fa7b-___AT=bfc97239f07a85ccb09e0cbce1555a2ea2abe062&___ID=19621b5b-c02d-4c68-99ec-919ae3d4d408&showInfoBar=false",
               "__utmb": "111701652.8.8.1565235799038"}

    session.get(login_url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, cookies=cookies)

    login_data = {"authenticityToken": "870fbf70782162d64481c1c05e3e8633d170d116",
                  "username": "USERNAME",
                  "password": "PASSWORD",
                  "g-recaptcha-response": "03AOLTBLSIaukc3aP8HmoksAgSGgmVrHoCy4KDGKkFqPmxVt8IE0mE_zSJd-VBYlYlbAmtawHeyd_krQX3J8q-MDTw6XVqorRI7kzVYARHbwsyr1sRdRs-IyEh_Pf3oogwgEiYXOOHCWXoB6piKPRFza7_gEaIkx9-iGUDsewbuZtcYePsTayaVNilF18NOjzMDhLs32g1r8vROZZh1Z9WuIYvlJDJhb62DIb-CLBXM1iQh_kSbpwmkBDL0CVMvOMMcfHM7NoEs9wcDReMqfBc53VFaSkNHKJ6Qh51fRd5hZSy1hgSlGCnQ5OdsJHDivxPB1DmdyGvvL9M"}

r1 = session.get(login_url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, cookies=cookies)
r2 = session.post(login_url, data=login_data, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, cookies=cookies)
```

The `authenticityToken` and `g-recaptcha-response` are just grabbed from my browser after a login attempt. I want to find a way to login without needing these 2 values, and I believe I just need to make the bot look as human as possible.

Is there anything missing or something I should add to be able to login?
Isn't it possible to login without the captcha using cookies or something of the sort?

Comment: use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox to see reuqest from browser to server when you login. It send more data - `authenticityToken, username, password, g-recaptcha-response` - It also call Google Recaptcha before login which probably sends data which you have to add in `g-recaptcha-response`.

Comment: some servers may block you if they have your proxy server on its blacklist. But you can't get this list.

Comment: @furas I've tried adding `authenticityToken` and `g-recaptcha-response` but they are always randomly generated after completing a captcha. There's no way I can get the correct values for them.

Also, I've tried logging in with and without proxies.

Comment: and this is why people use g-recaptcha - it stops others to steel data :)

Comment: I'm not attempting to steal data. I know g-recaptcha's purpose. But when I log into the website through my browser, I don't always get a captcha. I'm guessing that is because the website detects I'm a human user, and it will send me a captcha after a few logins or after some time. it has to be possible for me to get past it.

Comment: for some pages script should behave like human - send all headers/cookies like real browser, load pages with random delay, response with random delay, maybe even read all items like images, css, js (even if you don't need them) and run javascript which may send important data - like recaptcha. Using Selenium you can control web server and resolve some problems with headers, cookies, javascript but as I know some portals can recognize Selenium beacause it has to use JavaScript to control browser.

Comment: I've created a program that logs in using Selenium. How it works is by taking control of a manually opened chrome browser with Selenium, and automatically logging in. I rarely get a recaptcha when I use this method. I would love to be able to do the same with the requests module.

Comment: if you use `Session()` then you can set some headers, cookies, proxies at start and it will remeber them so you don't have to use it again in every `get/post`. But some elements are chagened in every requests - like cookies - so you can't use always the same values. Session is mostly because it care of cookies. It get new cookies from one request and send them in next request. If you use `cookies=cookies` then don't use in headers `Cookies`. It is the same elements so you can overwrite good cookies with wrong cookies.

Comment: There are other elements which may not be the same in requests - ie. `'Content-Type'`, `'Referer'`. `GET` doesn't uses `'Content-Type'` and `POST` use `Content-Length` with `'Content-Type'` but these elements should `requests` adds automatically. You would have to use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox to see all headers in all requests and recreate the same headers in your requests. And check it few times because cookies can changed in requests - server may update some cookies every hour for security reason.

Comment: The last probles are random values like `authenticityToken"`, `"g-recaptcha-response"`. They can be generated by JavaScript but requests doesn't run JS so you will have to get JavaScript code and rewrite it in Python - and it makes big problem. Code may use libraries which you have to rewrite or replace. They can also send data to server so you will have to do the same.

Comment: thank you very much for the help, I'm currently updating my code. I am willing to go through all the trouble if there is a guarantee that it will make things work